# Why can only the ES6 form of setTimeout see my React props?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

When I try to call a redux action creator like this, it fails because this.props is undefined.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    birthday = window.document.getElementById('birthday')
    this.props.actions.setBirthday(birthday.value)
  }, 100);
```

But when I use the ES6 version like this, the props are accessible and it works.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    birthday = window.document.getElementById('birthday')
    this.props.actions.setBirthday(birthday.value)
  }, 100)
```

Why? I'm an advanced-beginner and would like to understand this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this

Comment: Great thanks. I can see how this question could be a dupe in a pure javascript context. I'm inexperienced enough that I was focused on why the behavior was different in a React/Redux context, but I realize that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

That's because arrow functions have fixed context, the same as the parent function. In regular functions however, the context can change.

See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this) for more information.